# How to assign output of a command to a variable in code build

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to build a docker image whenever there is push to my source code and move the docker image to the ECR( EC2 Container Registry).

I have tried with the following build-spec file

```
    version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    IMG: "app"
    REPO: "<<zzzzzzzz>>.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app"      
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1
      - TAG=echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $TAG
      - docker build -t $IMG:$TAG .
      - docker tag $IMG:$TAG $REPO:$TAG 
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPO:$TAG
      - printf Image":"%s:%s" $REPO $TAG > build.json
artifacts:
  files: build.json
  discard-paths: yes
```

when I build this I am receiving the error `invalid reference format` at docker build -t

I looked into the document and found no help.

Answer (score 2):

```
TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)
```

you can use $()

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the install phase...
      - TAG=$(echo "This is test")
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo $TAG
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the build phase...
      - echo Build started on $TAG
```

Logs:

```
[Container] 2018/03/17 16:15:31 Running command TAG=$(echo "This is test")
[Container] 2018/03/17 16:15:31 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2018/03/17 16:15:31 Running command echo $TAG
This is test
```

Comment: Hi Sudarshan, I tried this today but no luck. I have added echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION command in the pre-build stage, it resulted in nothing. Could you please provide me complete buildspec.yml

Comment: Thanks, Sudharsan.

Answer (score 1):

So after of lots of retries, i finally found my mistake.

Env **CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION** should be replaced with **CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION** environment variable because I am using codebuild to build directly from source repo in GitHub.

To log in to ecr, need to add `--no-include-email` option and wrap the command with $(). This will allow you to run docker login. My updated buildspec file would be similar below

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    REPO: "184665364105.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/app" 
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION
      - TAG=$(echo $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION | head -c 8)
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
  build:
    commands:
      - echo $TAG
      - echo $REPO
      - docker build --tag $REPO:$TAG .
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker push $REPO:$TAG
```