# How do you reference a an aws secrets manager secret "value", and apply this to a code build buildspec command?

Tags: docker, aws-codebuild, aws-secrets-manager

I am able to retrieve the secret in the buildspec (given https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-codebuild-adds-support-for-aws-secrets-manager/):

```
secrets-manager:
secret_key_param: secret_name
```

However, when doing so, it gives:

```
{"secret_key":"secret_value"}
```

I only need "**secret_value**", is there an easy way to do this within the code build buildspec?

**NOTE**: I have already seen: [How to assign output of a command to a variable in code build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334876/how-to-assign-output-of-a-command-to-a-variable-in-code-build), it does not answer the question! It just references the cli command to retrieve the value (as part of an overall json dump)

The end goal is to be able to:

```
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to DockerHub...
      - docker login --username XXXX --password "secret_value"
```

TIA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following buildspec to retrieve "**secret_value**":

```
version: 0.2

env:
  secrets-manager:
    secret_key_param: secret_name:secret_key

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to DockerHub...
      - docker login --username XXXX --password $secret_key_param
```

Comment: I tried this but got *** as value . What does that mean?

Comment: Hi Chandara, the secret value from Parameter Store or Secrets Manager is masked.

Comment: Here are the docs for the env secrets-manager syntax in the buildspec: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#secrets-manager-build-spec

Comment: Also I believe it is a better practice to login this way (passing the password in via stdin)


`echo $DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD | docker login -u $DOCKERHUB_USER --password-stdin`

Comment: Is there a way to unmask the value retrieved? I'm trying to troubleshoot codebuild and seeing "***" is not helpful.